# Website scrape error - Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to solve the error from the following code:

```
import scrapy 
    

  class microeconomics_edX(scrapy.Spider):
        


    name='microeconomics'
    
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.edx.org/course/microeconomics']
    
        start_urls=['https://www.edx.org/course/microeconomics']
        
        
        custom_settings = {'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/shopclues.csv'}
        
        def parse(self,response):
            titles=response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/h1').get()
            subtitles=reponse.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/p').get()
            uni=response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span').get()
            instructor=reponse.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[4]/div/a/div/div').get()
            ataglance=reponse.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/div/p').get()
            
            for item in zip(titles,subtitles,uni,instructor,ataglance):
                scrapped_info={
                    'title': item[0],
                    'subtitles': item[1],
                    'uni': item[2],
                    'instructor': item[3]
                    
                }
                
                yield scrapped_info
```

Comment: Please provide the error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

1. You wrote 'reponse' instead of 'response'
2. Your 'instructor' xpath is wrong and you'll realize you're getting 'None', this content is generated with javascript:

```html
<script data-rh="true" type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Course","@id":"https://www.edx.org/course/microeconomics","name":"Microeconomics","courseCode":"MITx+14.100x","url":"https://www.edx.org/course/microeconomics","about":"Economics & Finance","educationalCredentialAwarded":"edX Certificate","isAccessibleForFree":true,"inLanguage":"en-us","timeRequired":"W11","description":"<p>Use economic models to learn how prices and markets benefit society in the face of scarcity, and then apply those models to analyze policy.</p>","provider":[{"@type":"CollegeOrUniversity","name":"Massachusetts Institute of Technology","sameAs":"https://www.edx.org/school/mitx"}],"hasCourseInstance":[{"@type":"CourseInstance","instructor":[{"@type":"Person","name":"Jonathan Gruber"}],"startDate":"2021-09-07T16:00:00Z","endDate":"2021-11-23T17:00:00Z","name":"Microeconomics"}],"image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://prod-discovery.edx-cdn.org/media/course/image/1b473926-2554-4b9f-86ba-8e4c5debb8eb-eb606b5ea35e.small.jpg"},"courseSku":null}</script>
```

You can get it with regex if you want.

3. Since you your 'instructor' is 'None' your'e getting an error: `TypeError: zip argument #4 must support iteration`, when you'll scrape it correctly (and replace reponse with respone) it will work.

**Here is an alternative solution:**
Since it's generated with javascript from a json file you can just get it from there.

Make a request with scrapy with the json url: `https://www.edx.org/page-data/course/microeconomics/page-data.json` (don't forget to add the request headers), and just scrape it from there.